# Espresso Select item from Adapter View

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying to Click and Select an Item from Spinner View. I used the following code to select and click the item.

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is(selectionText))).perform(click());
```

In UI It shows the change of Spinner item selection and spinner dialog disappear as soon as it click. But selection item does not display as spinner text. I tried to debug the code and found on click I didn't get handle on onItemSelect method.

I tried to write custom matcher and found it return the correct result as per the condition. It is the issue with click only. How can I resolve it or debug click().

Comment: Have you tried this approach? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31537551/1525990

Comment: Yes, But I didn't perform last condition to check the value again.

Comment: So now is it working as you expected?

Comment: No it is not working :(

Comment: After click on Spinner item Dialog closed but value does not shown on spinner selection text

Comment: Try to click first in the spinner itself as in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615658/espresso-why-dont-spinners-close-after-selection/37683354#37683354